# PRACK Request using SIPSorcery

Tags: c#, sip

how to send a message PRACK?

I give so:

```
m_uac.CallRinging += (ISIPClientUserAgent uac, SIPResponse sipResponse) =>
{

if ((sipResponse.StatusCode == (int)SIPResponseStatusCodesEnum.SessionProgress ||
sipResponse.StatusCode == (int)SIPResponseStatusCodesEnum.Ringing) && 
sipResponse.Header.Require == "100rel")
    {
      m_uac.SendRequest(sipResponse, SIPMethodsEnum.PRACK, null, $"RAck: {sipResponse.Header.RSeq} {sipResponse.Header.CSeq} {sipResponse.Header.CSeqMethod}")
    }

 }
```

get errors:
*Exception CreateNonInviteTransaction. An attempt was made to add a duplicate SIP transaction.
Exception SIPNonInviteClientUserAgent SendRequest to sip:test@sip.srv_1.com. An attempt was made to add a duplicate SIP tra
Exception UACInviteTransaction_TransactionInformationResponseReceived. An attempt was made to add a duplicate SIP transaction.*

who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRACK's aren't supported in the SIPSorcery SIP implementation (they're not part of the main specification and aren't very common).

The approach would be to use the `uac.ServerInviteTransaction` to generate the PRACK request based on the `GetInTransactionACKRequest`.

A better place for this question would be on [github](https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/issues) and if you still have the need I can add it relatively quickly.

Comment: it would be great)